# Why is high spelled that way?

Tags: orthography, pronunciation-vs-spelling

Why is "high" pronounced "hiy" but is not spelled as the latter, but the former?

Wouldn't "high" be read as "heeg-h" or "haig-h"?

The other possible duplicate's examples all have a "t" prefixing, and also, the accepted answer for that question does not address why GH is occasionally pronounced out.

Example's of other words starting with "GH" is Ghillie, or ending with GH as in Edinburgh

Comment: The duplicate is itself a duplicate. Eventually it [points at this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/148033/15299).

Comment: "High" used to be pronounced with a guttural sort of "gh" or "kh" sound, rather like the cognate German "hoch", and our present-day spelling of "high" is a relic of that old pronunciation.