# Origin of "ight"

Tags: etymology, orthography

So many words end in "ight", such as "light", "might" and "sight".

I am curious about this -- is there an etymological reason why "ight" is used for many seemingly disparate words?

Thanks.

Comment: In Early Modern English. they were all pronounced with the "gh", a sound which has disappeared from our language, but is still heard in German *Licht* and *Sicht* (*light* and *sight*).

Comment: See https://english.stackexchange.com/a/148033/9368 for your answer.